# How do I perform an exact string match on a non-case sensitive field?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to find all the rows in a table and match on an exact case sensitive string. Unfortunately, my table has the case insensitive collation.

What is the most efficient way to perform this.

Eg.

I would like the following to return no rows:

```
select * from sysobject where name = 'Sysbinobjs'
```

For the answer assume @match is in a variable:

```
declare @match varchar(4000) 
set @match = 'sysbinobjs'
```

**EDIT**

Clarification, make sure trailing spaces are treated properly, I want an exact match that takes account of trailing spaces so 'Hello' will only be matched with 'Hello' and not with 'Hello     '

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a snippet of code that works, its really tricky to do this in a safe and efficient way. The double match is to avoid a table scan (look at the execution plan). The varbinary casting forces a length and case match. So trailing spaces are treated properly and casing is treated properly.

**Note** the type being compared needs to be identical to the type in the table for the varbinary casting to work (eg. name in sysobject is an nvarchar so the @match will need to be an nvarchar).

```
declare @match nvarchar(4000) 
set @match = 'sysbinobjs'


select * from sysobjects
where name = @match and
cast(name as varbinary(4000)) = cast(@match as varbinary(4000))
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually I don't see why you have to do the escaping first, this is built into SQL server through the COLLATE statment.

```
select * from sysobjects
WHERE name = @match and --Get all relevant hits from the index before doing the final case sensitive test
name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = @match COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Comment: I simplified my answer, the issue with this one is that trailing spaces are not treated properly, eg. 'hello' = 'hello    ', also I think the collate stuff is hard to remember when coding.

Comment: +1 You are a genius my friend, this solution worked great for me!!